# Is Khan Noonien Singh a follower of Sikhism?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, religion, the-wrath-of-khan, khan-singh

In TOS *Space Seed*, Lt. Marla McGivers identifies Khan Noonien Singh as a [Sikh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikh).

> (Looking at Khan) From the northern India area, I'd guess. Probably a Sikh. They were the most fantastic warriors.

Lt. McGivers' assessment is supported with Khan's last name being [Singh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singh), which is strongly associated with ethnic Sikhs and at one point was mandated for all baptized men.

Sikhs are also traditionally followers of [Sikhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikhism), a religion in which one of its tenets is [Kesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kesh_(Sikhism)), the practice of growing out one's beard naturally. Guru Gobind Singh Ji explained this reason, noting in particular facial hair.

> My Sikh shall not use the razor. For him the use of razor or shaving the chin shall be as sinful as incest. For the Khalsa such a symbol is prescribed so that his Sikhs can be classified as pure.

Does the fact that Khan is clean-shaven, in violation of Kesh, indicate that he is not a follower of Sikhism despite being an ethnic Sikh?

[image: Khan Noonien Singh]

I'm open to answers from any level of canon.

Comment: A character expresses an opinion that he *could* be a Sikh is not the same as a definitive statement he is.  So the obvious conclusion is that he's not a Sikh and therefore not violating Kesh.

Comment: @StephenG I've changed my question to ask if he's a follower of Sikhism, as opposed to an ethnic Sikh.

Comment: While the Kesh aspect of Sikhism is followed by several people with the surname Singh, there are also many who don't. Here's [Yuvraj Singh](https://f1.media.brightcove.com/8/3588749423001/3588749423001_4918120280001_yuvrajvideo.jpg?pubId=3588749423001&videoId=4918017308001), one of the most popular cricketers in India.

Comment: `shall be as sinful as incest.` - Possible squickiness:  TOS-era they were created by selective breeding, not genetic manipulation (that was a later retcon).  Perhaps they crossed that boundary and it no longer mattered?

Comment: In the scene aboard the Botany Bay when Khan is being woken from suspended animation, McGivers says: MARLA: From the northern India area, I'd guess. Probably a Sikh. They were the most fantastic warriors.   Later in the sickbay Khan says his name is Khan.  Khan is not identified until later, after the dinner:  KIRK: Name, Khan, as we know him today. (Spock changes the picture) Name, Khan Noonien Singh. Marla's assessment was not based on knowledge of his name.  Singh is a popular name among non Sikhs as well.

Comment: Khan believes in God,  but he's convinced that it's him.

Comment: @Valorum What does God need with a starship?

Comment: I'm not sure there is such a thing as an "ethnic Sikh" - a Sikh is by definition a follower of Sikhism, regardless of ethnic origin. Most Sikhs are from the Punjab region of India so are ethnically _Punjabi_, back in 1967 though the distinction probably wasn't apparent hence Khan "looks" like a "Sikh". The fact that he is clean shaven and so is almost certainly not a Sikh was obviously missed by the writers.

Comment: Also the phrase "Sikhs are also traditionally followers of Sikhism" is fundamentally wrong as it implies there are Sikhs who are not followers of Sikhism, which is by definition impossible.

Comment: @Nathan It was my understanding that one could be an ethnic Sikh without being an adherent to the religion. Is there a better way I could phrase this?

Answer (score 7):

This is addressed in the [*Eugenics Wars*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Eugenics_Wars) trilogy of EU novels, detailing the life and times of Khan.

**He was raised in a Sikh family.**

> Although raised as a Sikh, albeit a fairly secular one, Khan was
> inclined to create his own traditions, and, as there was no one on
> Ceti Alpha V whose authority exceeded his own, he found it altogether
> proper that he officiate over his own wedding. “Do you take I, Khan
> Noonien Singh, as your lawfully wedded husband, to share the bounty
> and adversities of this brave new world as my one and only queen?”
>
> <sub><sup>[To Reign in Hell: The Exile of Khan Noonien Singh](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/To_Reign_in_Hell:_The_Exile_of_Khan_Noonien_Singh)</sup></sub>

**He isn't religious (per se), but he does seem to believe in divine beneficence.**

> Despite his Sikh ancestry, Khan was not a religious man, but right now
> he gladly welcomed whatever divine assistance might be available. If
> not for me, he bargained, then for the injured Joaquin, who fell in my
> service.
>
> <sub><sup>[*The Rise and Fall of Khan Noonien Singh. Vol. 2*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Rise_and_Fall_of_Khan_Noonien_Singh,_Volume_Two?so=search)</sup></sub>

**His lack of a beard was a conscious decision on his part to break with his (non-superhuman) ancestors.**

> “What’s up with the close shave?” she asked him glibly, stalling for time while she recovered from her shock-induced trip to dreamland. “The last time I saw you, back in eighty-nine, you were sporting a respectable-looking beard. I thought that was mandatory for all male Sikhs?”
>
> Khan nodded, smiling appreciatively. “Very good, Ms. Lincoln. I applaud your cross-cultural erudition.” He thoughtfully stroked his smooth and stubble-free chin. **“With all due respect to my heroic Sikh ancestors, however, I eventually came to the conclusion that I should not be bound by the traditions of the past. I am a new breed of human being, after all. A new and superior kind of warrior. Thus, on my twenty-first birthday, I shaved off my beard, in recognition of the revolutionary turning point that I, and the others like me, represent in the history of human evolution.** Henceforth, I resolved, I would make my own traditions, chart a new path for mankind.”
>
> <sub><sup>[*The Rise and Fall of Khan Noonien Singh. Vol. 2*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Rise_and_Fall_of_Khan_Noonien_Singh,_Volume_Two?so=search)</sup></sub>

Comment: Odd that he'd choose then, given that a twenty-first birthday is generally only significant to Americans.

Comment: @OrangeDog - This is, of course, in an alternate reality from our own.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious Khan doesn't follow the rules bound with Sikhism. Yes, it is a tradition in Sikhs to trim their beards but in the end it's the will of the person if he wants it clean shaven or wants to follow the rules of Sikhism.

Also being an Indian I know for a fact that not all Singh's are necessarily Sikhs. Taking into consideration what Valorum has written that Khan was a indeed a Sikh then it should also be pointed that he doesn't wear a turban which is one of the most recognizable traits of a Sikh.

Comment: What that means is that he's not a very good Sikh, not that he's not necessarily one at all :-)